# Group JSON based on ID

Tags: java, spring, java-8, collectors

i have a json

```
{  
  "content": [
    {
      "idnumber": "666",
      "name": "mark",
      "type": "band",
      "tools": [
        {
          "idtools": "5657",
          "blabla": null,
          "blabla": false,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "idnumber": "666",
      "name": "mark",
      "type": "band",
      "tools": [
        {
          "idtools": "5658",
          "blabla": null,
          "blabla": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

inside content array, i have 2 json. i want to change my json into this, because they have same id number.

```
{  
  "content": [
    {
      "idnumber": "666",
      "name": "mark",
      "type": "band",
      "tools": [
        {
          "idtools": "5657",
          "blabla": null,
          "blabla": false,
        },
        {
          "idtools": "5658",
          "blabla": null,
          "blabla": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

how to do that using distinct or filter?

i tried to distinct it and map it but still have error.

Comment: Did you tried something ? can you show us your code please ?

Comment: You might want to post the DTO structure instead of JSON. This is a pure Java problem.

Comment: @YCF_L i tried using hashset. and distinct still failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following objects that match your JSON structure (for sake of brevity, I use Lombok):

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Content {
    int idNumber;
    String name;
    String type;
    List<Tool> tools;
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class Tool {
    int idTools;
    String blabla;
}
```

You can use the Stream API with `groupingBy` by the `id` and `reduce` the values into a single one.

```
 List<Content> mergedContents = contents.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Content::getIdNumber))
     .values()
     .stream()
     .reduce(
          new ArrayList<>(),                               // mutable List
          (left, right) -> {
              Content content = right.get(0);              // they are same (by id)
              List<Tool> tools = right.stream()            // from each new list
                      .flatMap(c -> c.getTools().stream()) // .. flatmap the tools
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());       // .. and extract to a list
              content.setTools(tools);                     // set the List<Tool>
              left.add(content);                           // add the Content
              return left;                                 // return the left list
          },
          (left, right) -> left);                          // only for parallel Stream
```

The resulting structure comming from `Collectors.groupingBy(Content::getIdNumber)` is `Map<Integer, List<Content>>`. The subsequent mutable reduction on the map values (`Collection<List<Content>>`) merges each `List<Content>` with identical `Content.id` into a single `Content` with flatmapped `List<Tools>`. The List with a these modified `Content` is returned as a result of the reduction.

**Sample data**

```
List<Content> contents = new ArrayList<>();
contents.add(new Content(666, "Mark", "Band", 
        Collections.singletonList(new Tool(5657, null))));
contents.add(new Content(666, "Mark", "Band", 
        Collections.singletonList(new Tool(5658, null))));

List<Content> mergedContents = /* solution */

mergedContents.forEach(System.out::println);
```

> `Main.Content(idNumber=666, name=Mark, type=Band, tools=[Main.Tool(idTools=5657, blabla=null), Main.Tool(idTools=5658, blabla=null)])`

This is equal to what your JSON samples.

Comment: ooohhh maaaaannn!! Great explanation! straight to the point. it works. i think i should learn more about "reduce, flatmap, etc". btw,  thanks for your answer. best!